# pass and name variables

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I'm a beginner of Java and trying to figure out building a JScrollPane. I have following codes so far but it's having a problem calling JScrollPane. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
public class DemoTest {

    public String sTEXT = null;
    public JTextArea jTEXTAREA = null;
    public JScrollPane jPANE = null;
    public JFrame jFRAME = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoTest demo = new DemoTest();
    }

    public DemoTest() {
        setText();
        setPane();
        setFrame();
    }

    public void setFrame() {
        JFrame jFRAME = new JFrame("Demo");

        jFRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFRAME.setSize(350, 300);
        jFRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFRAME.setVisible(true);
        jFRAME.add(jPANE); // **THIS SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM**
    }

    public void setPane() {
        JScrollPane jPANE = new JScrollPane(jTEXTAREA);
    }

    public void setText() {
        JTextArea jTEXTAREA = new JTextArea();
        jTEXTAREA.setText("Hello World!");
        jTEXTAREA.setEditable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this.jFRAME (or don't create a variable with the same name where a class variable exists) to assign to the class variable otherwise you will not be initializing those variables.

Comment: You're making many extreme newbie mistakes in the code above, mistakes that suggest that you will want to back up and study the basics first before tackling GUI programming.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempted to create the various Swing Objects, you were creating new local variables instead of assigning to the member variables (class level). Note that if you have a member variable and local variable of the same name, you may assign to the member variable by using `this.VAR_NAME = ...;`. For a better understanding of variable scope, read this [Scope of Variables in Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) post which explains the basics well.

```
public class DemoTest {

    public  String          sTEXT           = null;
    public  JTextArea       jTEXTAREA       = null;
    public  JScrollPane     jPANE           = null;
    public  JFrame          jFRAME          = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoTest demo = new DemoTest();
    }

    public DemoTest(){
        setText();
        setPane();
        setFrame();
    }

    public void setFrame(){
        jFRAME = new JFrame ("Demo");
        jFRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFRAME.setSize(350,300);
        jFRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFRAME.setVisible(true);
        jFRAME.add(jPANE);

    }

    public void setPane(){
        jPANE = new JScrollPane(jTEXTAREA);
    }

    public void setText(){
        jTEXTAREA= new JTextArea();
        jTEXTAREA.setText("Hello World!");
        jTEXTAREA.setEditable(false);
    }
}
```